# Place the `CROSS` outside the modal

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-modal

[image]I use `react-native-modal` and how can I place the `CROSS` outside the modal, in the corner of the backdrop? If I use `absolute` positioning, then the `CROSS` is found under the background layer.

```
      <>
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.cross}>
          <Image source={CROSS} />
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <Modal>
         {....}
        </Modal>
      </>

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  cross: {
    position: 'absolute',
    zIndex: 100,
    elevation: 100,
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must place cross inside modal. Modal takes whole screen. And other content of modal content place next to cross as sibling. :

```
<Modal>
  <TouchableOpacity style={styles.cross}>
    <Image source={CROSS} />
  </TouchableOpacity>
 {....}
</Modal>
```

Comment: not working. The background takes up the entire screen space, no matter where the cross is

Comment: Then you must place cross inside modal. Modal takes whole screen. And other content of modal content place next to cross as sibling.